# How to add a column which match characters and fill with 0 the others

Tags: r

If we have a dataframe A which contains dates.. and we have a dataframe B which contains part of the reference dates like this:

```
A:
    Year      Month      Day      X
    1990      01         01      55
    1991      03         02      324
    1992      04         11      56
    1993      06         07      4
    1994      08         12      5


B:
    Year      Month      Day      Y
    1990      01         01      1
    1991      03         02      2
    1992      04         11      3
```

How could I add the column Y of dataframe B to the dataframe A matching the dates. Besides, the dates that are not present in B dataframe fill them with 0, like this:

```
A:
        Year      Month      Day      X      Y
        1990      01         01      55      1
        1991      03         02      324     2
        1992      04         11      56      3
        1993      06         07      4       0
        1994      08         12      5       0
```

Comment: `merge(x = A, y = B, all.x = T)`. You can then replace `NA` with `0` in the result.

Comment: This operation is called a "left join", you might want to read up on [different types of joins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20298671/903061).

Comment: Gregor, do you have any advise about how to start to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48835464/how-to-manage-a-table-to-obtain-information-using-conditions